# Cannot make the OWASP.ESAPI library to start up. Configuration issue?

Tags: spring-boot, sql-injection, esapi

I need to set up this lib to encode the SQL queries. In my Spring Boot app (11th Java) I added to POM.xml the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
    <artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0.0</version> 
</dependency>
```

Added to the resources the ESAPI.properties file w/ the following content:

```
ESAPI.Encoder=org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder
Encoder.AllowMultipleEncoding=false
Encoder.AllowMixedEncoding=false
Encoder.DefaultCodecList=HTMLEntityCodec,PercentCodec,JavaScriptCodec
ESAPI.Logger=org.owasp.esapi.logging.slf4j.Slf4JLogFactory
```

And during the unit test execution i catch this exception:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Encoder class (org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder) CTOR threw exception.
```

BTW as a logging subsystem I use logback.

Adding stacktrace

```
"2021-12-07T14:18:54.298+03:00","level":"ERROR","logger_name":"bankclient.controller.GlobalControllerExceptionHandler","application":"BANKCLIENT","app_version":"undefined","thread_name":"main","message":"Undefined request processing error",
"stackTrace":"org.owasp.esapi.errors.ConfigurationException: SecurityConfiguration for Logger.LogEncodingRequired not found in ESAPI.properties
\org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultSecurityConfiguration.getBooleanProp(DefaultSecurityConfiguration.java:1354)
    at 
org.owasp.esapi.logging.slf4j.Slf4JLogFactory.<clinit>(Slf4JLogFactory.java:53)
    ... 147 common frames omitted

Wrapped by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at 
java.lang.Class.forName0(Class.java)
    at 
java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
    at  org.owasp.esapi.util.ObjFactory.loadClassByStringName(ObjFactory.java:158)
    at 
org.owasp.esapi.util.ObjFactory.make(ObjFactory.java:81)
    at 
org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.logFactory(ESAPI.java:137)
    at org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.getLogger(ESAPI.java:153)
    at org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder.<init>(DefaultEncoder.java:83)
    at org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder.getInstance(DefaultEncoder.java:67)
    ... 
139 common frames omitted

Wrapped by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at  jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at  jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.owasp.esapi.util.ObjFactory.make(ObjFactory.java:86)
    ... 
134 common frames omitted

Wrapped by: org.owasp.esapi.errors.ConfigurationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Encoder class (org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder) CTOR threw exception.
    at 
org.owasp.esapi.util.ObjFactory.make(ObjFactory.java:129)
    at org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.encoder(ESAPI.java:99)
    at  bankclient.repository.currency.JdbcCurrencyOperationRepository.findOperationsWithDateAndDocType(JdbcCurrencyOperationRepository.java:220)
    at bankclient.interactors.documents.currency.operations.CurrencyDocumentViewer.execute(CurrencyDocumentViewer.java:25)
    at
```

Why this exception is thrown? Did I missed some steps in configuration?
Are there smth. like a Spring Boot starter for esapi library?

Comment: Please include the full stacktrace.

Comment: Added a stacktrace, Unfortunately it is not complete and not properly formatted but i tried to include to it the most important entries. Thanks for assist!

Comment: `"stackTrace":"org.owasp.esapi.errors.ConfigurationException: SecurityConfiguration for Logger.LogEncodingRequired not found in ESAPI.properties` looks like to explain what is wrong.

Comment: I added `Logger.LogEncodingRequired=false` to `ESAPI.properties` and the error is gone.

Comment: @M.Deinum, a good point! Now everything is fine. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @samabcde actually your suggestion was the key point. Now everything is fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is wrong is actually in plain sight.

> `stackTrace":"org.owasp.esapi.errors.ConfigurationException: SecurityConfiguration for Logger.LogEncodingRequired not found in ESAPI.properties`

You are missing a property in your `ESAPI.properties` file, the `Logger.LogEncodingRequired` property is missing. Which is this message telling you (quite explicitly if I might add).

Add

```
Logger.LogEncodingRequired=false # Or true if you need this
```

to your properties and this error should be gone.